# Cannot attempt to google cloud console instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

[image: https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz]

I was able to login via ssh normally but it just stopped working.
I tried to stop and start instance but it doesn't help. Could anybody help?

Comment: You should follow the documentation [Viewing serial port output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) and update your question with output to provide community more information. In addition, have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) and update your question with steps you've tried.

Comment: Did you change something in the project/organisation configuration/restrictions?

Comment: I don't think I didn't change configuration

Answer (score 0):

You could check your Firewall Rules in GCP console and if it is not created you can create the rule and with port number 22

**$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22**

After try to connect to SSH...

Comment: I think this isn't a problem. I was attempting to server in the yesterday and it just happened. Also 22 port already opened

Comment: is it working fine now and are you able to connect to SSH !

Comment: I moved my original instance to new instance